# How to hide a video overlay in leafletJS after playing?

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, leaflet

I am building a site with an video overlay on a leafletJS map and I would love the video to disappear (like a trailer) after it was played once.

I am a newbie in JS so I tried a lot - I guess it has to do with an onended event:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onended_video

maybe the layer could be hided or opacity could be set to 0.0?

Thats what my map is looking like now:

http://dominique.turzer.eu/index.php/de/

I would really appreciate any help in finding a solution for my problem!!!

```
<body>
    <div id="mapid" style="width: 80em; height: 50em;"></div>
    <script>

        var mapid = L.map('mapid').setView([41.8939551, 12.479556], 14);

        L.tileLayer('https://stamen-tiles-{s}.a.ssl.fastly.net/watercolor/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            maxZoom: 18,
            attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
                '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
                'Imagery © <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen</a>',
            id: 'mapbox.streets'
        }).addTo(mapid);

        var videoUrls = [
            'http://dominique.turzer.eu/media/mod_osmod/images/Film8.mp4'
        ];
        var bounds = L.latLngBounds([[41.92398333, 12.45647433], [41.863167640465, 12.502337292]]);

        var videoOverlay = L.videoOverlay(videoUrls, bounds, {
            opacity: 0.7,
            loop: false
        }).addTo(mapid);


    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: @IvanSanchez - Video are not autoplaying in Chrome 67 and so remains as image on the map, do you know how I could make it play or disappear, when chrome is detected? Thanks for help. My betasite is: dominique.turzer.eu

Comment: Open a new question for that.

Comment: Thanks, I just did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your video overlay:

```
var videoOverlay = L.videoOverlay(videoUrls, bounds, {
    opacity: 0.7,
    loop: false
}).addTo(mapid);
```

[Get a reference](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#videooverlay-getelement) to the [`HTMLVideoElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLVideoElement) for the video overlay:

```
var videoElement = videoOverlay.getElement();
```

[Attach an event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to the [`ended` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/ended) of the `HTMLVideoElement`. In that event handler, [remove](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#layer-remove) the video overlay from its map:

```
videoElement.addEventListener('ended', function(){
    videoOverlay.remove();
});
```

You can, alternatively, use the Leaflet DOM event wrapper:

```
L.DomEvent.on(videoElement, 'ended', function(){
    videoOverlay.remove();
});
```

Comment: Works very fine! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Turzer: Please note that the SO way to thank people is also to _accept_ the answer that helped you solve your question. That way, people also know your issue is fixed. Once you get enough _reputation_, you will also get the ability to _upvote_.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want it for the first visit you can use cookie.
You check if it's defined or not with this :

```
document.cookie.indexOf('trailer') > -1
```

It will return `false` for the first time. Do your things and then update your cookie

```
document.cookie = "trailer=true"
```

For your video you can simply do that :

```
$('video').on('ended',function(){
    // Remove your video from the map
    map.removeLayer(video)
});
```